# Georeferenced Rasters from QGIS to ESRI: coordinate system problem

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing

I have georeferenced rasters in QGIS (2.18). We assigned a coordinate system to the image: EPSG 26917, which is NAD83 Zone 17N. When i then bring this image into ESRI, the coordinate system is redefined as some custom projection called "UTM_Zone_17_Northern_Hemisphere" with a made up GCS but which otherwise matches the standard UTM 17 in ESRI. 
What i can't understand is why it's doing this - the ID for the system is correct in QGIS, but ESRI won't accept it - even though ESRI also uses EPSG ID's and NAD83 17N is the same in both programs. Because the systems don't match, i can't then edit the rasters as i need to. I have to keep this bogus projection and re-project all my images as i go.

Comment: What's the raster file format? and ArcGIS version?

Comment: @mkennedy - sorry I missed your reply. 
Format is JPG or TIFF - we have a mixed bag.
ArcMap 10.7